# Processing Making PImage with PGraphics

Tags: processing

I'm trying a simple masking of an image with a circle shape on top of it.

I don't understand why it is not working. The image gets printed correctly, but not a sing of a mask. This is my code:

```
PImage lion;
PGraphics mask;

void setup() {  
  size(720, 380);

  lion = loadImage("lion.jpg");

  mask = createGraphics(720, 380);
  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.ellipse(0, 0, 150, 150);
  mask.fill(0, 0, 0);
  mask.endDraw();

  mask.mask(lion);
}

void draw() {
  image(lion, 0, 0);
}
```

The lion image is just random image from google.

Comment: Can you detail what do you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the `mask` to the `lion` image and not to apply the `lion` image as a mask to the `mask`.
The first 2 parameters of the [`ellipse()`](https://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html) are the x and y center coordinates of the ellipse.
Fill the entire `mask` with a black background and then draw a white ellipse to center of the mask:

```java
void setup() {
    size(720, 380);

    lion = loadImage("lion.jpg");
    int w = lion.width;
    int h = lion.height;

    mask = createGraphics(w, h);
    mask.beginDraw();
    mask.background(0);
    mask.fill(255);
    mask.ellipse(w/2, h/2, w, h);
    mask.endDraw();

    lion.mask(mask);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    image(lion, 0, 0);
}
```